# Inheritance between constructors[CLOSE]

Tags: c++, class, inheritance

So I have a constructor in class `LimitedBankAccount` and it has inherits class `BankAccount` (*In short constructor calling to another constructor)*.

```
BankAccount::BankAccount(std::string name)
{
    _name = name;
    _balance = 0;
}

LimitedBankAccount::LimitedBankAccount(double limit) : BankAccount(_name)
{
    _limit = limit;
}
```

So my question is this: How do I call the constructor of `LimitedBankAccount` so that the name in `BankAccount` will be in `LimitedBankAccount`, and also keep the both together.

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want your LimitedBankAccount constructor to include a name parameter as well:

```
// Note that you can use an initializer list to set your member variables
BankAccount::BankAccount(std::string name)
: _name(name), _balance(0)
{ }

LimitedBankAccount::LimitedBankAccount(std::string name, double limit)
: BankAccount(name), _limit(limit)
{ }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
LimitedBankAccount::LimitedBankAccount(double limit, string name) : BankAccount(name)
{
    _limit = limit;
}
```

Comment: If I now print my on linked list of LimitedBankAccount I will get the names from BankAccount?

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide a "name" argument in your derived constructor, too. Best to write it with initializer lists:

```
BankAccount::BankAccount(std::string name)
: _name(std::move(name))
, _balance()
{ }

LimitedBankAccount::LimitedBankAccount(double limit, std::string name)
: BankAccount(std::move(name))
, _limit(limit)
{ }
```

Usage:

```
LimiteBankAccount account(100.0, "Jane Doe");
```